# Some points in my isometric grid are not aligning

Tags: adobe-illustrator, isometric

I created this isometric grid, via the SSR method described in [this tutorial](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-create-an-isometric-grid-in-less-than-2-minutes--vector-3831).

However, when drawing a rectangle, and copy-dragging it the 'rectangles' do not align. When drawing a straight line i see that the grid is not perfect vertically although i followed every step;

1: create grid (1000/1000 pixels, 30 collunms 30 rows)
2: scale the grid vertically (86.602 %)
3: shear 30 degrees
4: rotate -45 degrees
5: make guides

[image: Rectangle drawn on grid]
[image: Rectangles not aligning]
[image: Straight line on grid, points not aligning]

I tried it again and again and i never get a perfect grid. Working on windows 7  // Illustrator CC 2014

Comment: Quick guess: try turning off `Align to pixel grid`?

Comment: That was my guess as well, I turned it off and re-did everything, no improvements. What I did notice is that the offset is happening every 2 steps, so it looks like its 'swinging': http://i.stack.imgur.com/3G7oI.png

Comment: The post is quite recent. Did you try asking the author? (If you get a response don't forget to post it as an answer!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that you had "Align to pixel grid" checked in the advanced settings of the document setup window, so all new objects you created were being aligned to the pixel grid.

That's why "re-doing it" didn't solve the problem. If this is the case you'll have to create a new document and make sure the option isn't checked in advanced settings.

Please see this thread for more detail:

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/675541?start=0&tstart=0