# Are isometric grids vertically matching points at 90deg?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, isometric

This is a continuation of a question about how [some points are not aligning](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41647/some-points-in-my-isometric-grid-are-not-aligning). I am using the same tutorial as them, and I do not have snap-to-pixel on. However, I check the points of each corner to see the x-coordinate does not match the one that is above or below. Is this supposed to happen? Or is this an Illustrator related issue?

[image: Arrows drawn towards points that have x-coordinates that do not match]

Comment: are you sure your following that exact tutorial. Because there has been a longstanding problem with SSR instructions where there was a typo in the original tutorial so since everybody was copying the wrong value for the scale. seems to be correct here though. So care to go through your exact steps. No there is no general issue with illustrator it works fine if you did in fact use right numbers.

Comment: @joojaa I tried it again and this time it worked! Maybe I touched it a little after making the grid? Anyway, thank you.